# Подскажите, почему он меняет переменную a? Язык Си

Tags: c, строки, структуры

[image: После выполнения strcpy(n->x, b)]никак не могу осознать по какой причине программа вообще трогает переменную а в первом условии второго цикла

суть функции в том, что есть структура, в которой хранятся строки, нужно поменять местами две строки

структура следующая:

```
struct Mas {
  char x[100];
  struct Mas *y;
};

struct Mas *obmen(struct Mas *start, char *a, char *b) {
  int k1 = 0, k2 = 0, k = 1;
  struct Mas *n, *str;
  char *str1, *str2;
  printf("Какие строки нужно поменять?\n");
  scanf_s("%d%d", &k1, &k2);
  n = start;
  while (getchar() != '\n');

  if (n != NULL)
    do {
      if (k == k1) {
        a = n->x;
      }
      if (k == k2) {
        b = n->x;
      }
      k++;
      n = n->y;

    } while (n != NULL);

  n = start;
  k = 1;
  if (n != NULL)
    do {
      if (k == k1) {
        strcpy(n->x, b);
      }
      if (k == k2) {
        strcpy(n->x, a);
      }
      k++;
      n = n->y;
    } while (n != NULL);

  printf("Строка встречается %d раз\n\n", k);
  return start;
}
```

Comment: нужно поменять местами две строки, а функция печатает, что какая-то строка встречается сколько-то раз. Так все-таки, ф-ция занимается подсчетом или обменом?

Comment: _"`while (getchar() != '\n');`"_ - это вечный цикл.

Comment: а вы посмотрите на адрес переменной a и переменной n

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему?

Comment: Обменом, про подсчет, это старый код от которого остался только вывод
а почему адрес идентичен? Я совсем туплю
ну тоесть это же разные переменные

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, согласен, ошибся.

Comment: @ТатьянаКайнова ну и что, что переменные разные? Адреса у переменных одинаковые. Изменения по этому адресу и подсветились красным цветом.

Comment: Эту часть я поняла, я про то, почему у них оказался один адрес
то есть причину я осознала, теперь проблема в том, что я не понимаю с чего так.
Это не из-за приравнивания в первом цикле?

Comment: @ТатьянаКайнова x - лежит по 0-му смещению структуры Mas (если посмотрите повнимательней, это так же видно в отладчике), т.е. в момент `a = n->x` - вы по сути присвоили адрес на структуру.

Comment: О, я поняла!
Полагаю последний вопрос, весьма глупый.
Есть ли способ записать сами данные, а не адрес?

Comment: @Татьяна Кайнова: "Сами данные" строки копируются при помощи функции `strcpy`.